# Get the derivative function plot from a NDSolve solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I been trying to plot the derivative function of j[t], being j'[t]. Here a look to the code.[image: Screenshot from the code] I would appreciate your help. Thank you

```
g = 9.81; ve = 20.47; mr = 0.3; mw = 0.75; b = 0.0024052;
J = NDSolve[{j'[
     t] == -(g - (mw*ve^2*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr + 
        mw*Exp[-ve*t])) + (mw*ve*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t])*
      j[t] - (b/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t]))*j[t]^2, j[0] == 0}, j[t], {t, 0, 
5}] 

Plot[j[t]/.J , {t, 0,10}, PlotRange -> {-60,60}]

Plot[Evaluate[j'[t]/.J], {t, 0,10}, PlotRange -> {-100,100}]
```

Comment: `dj=D[j[t]/.J,t]; Plot[dj,{t,0,10},PlotRange->All]` seems to work just fine with no other changes

Comment: Great, it seems to work fine, however and as other question, how do you do it in order to get the integrated function of j[t]? @Bill

Comment: `s=Integrate[(j[t]/.J)[[1]],{t,0,x}]; Plot[s,{x,0,8}]` seems to work just fine. Test all this very carefully to make certain that it is correct.

Comment: You can integrate an `InterpolatingFunction` directly: `Integrate[j[t] /. First[J], t]`

Answer (score 1):

Try `NDSolveValue`

```
J = NDSolveValue[{j'[t] == -(g - (mw*ve^2*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr +mw*Exp[-ve*t])) + (mw*ve*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t])*j[t] - (b/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t]))*j[t]^2, j[0] == 0}, j, {t,0,5}] 

Plot[ J'[t] , {t, 0,10}, PlotRange -> {-100,100}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Request the function `j`, not the expression `j[t]`, from `NDSolve`:

```
g = 9.81; ve = 20.47; mr = 0.3; mw = 0.75; b = 0.0024052;
J = NDSolve[{j'[t] == -(g - (mw*ve^2*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr + 
        mw*Exp[-ve*t])) + (mw*ve*Exp[-ve*t])/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t])*
      j[t] - (b/(mr + mw*Exp[-ve*t]))*j[t]^2, j[0] == 0},
  j, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Then `J` will have the form of (a nested list containing) a substitution rule `{{j -> ...}}` and it will replace `j` in `j'[t]` by the interpolating function solution `NDSolve` computed; this function will be automatically differentiated.  The following then will work:

```
Plot[Evaluate[j'[t] /. J], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-100, 100}]
```

Some find getting the function directly from `NDSolveValue` convenient (see @Ulrich's answer), which I do at times.  If I need to plug `j` into various expressions, the substitution rule is very convenient.  On the other hand, a substitution rule of the form `j[t] -> ...` is less convenient because it cannot be used to replace `j'[t]` with the solution. I never use that form.